# INSERT new history rows based on results from UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I'd like to

```
UPDATE table SET column = 1 where column = 0;

INSERT (rows i just updated) INTO history_table;
```

Can I somehow store the ids from a select query, and then use those to UPDATE and subsequently INSERT rows matching those ids into the history table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add every update, delete, insert query to a new record in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697733/add-every-update-delete-insert-query-to-a-new-record-in-mysql)

Comment: You will need to save the rows where column = 0 into the history_table before changing them. If the history table contains other rows, you may need to use a pre_history_table, set them to zero, then insert into history_table.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO history_table(id)
(SELECT id from table WHERE column = 0);`

`UPDATE table SET column = 1 where column = 0;`

This way you are only getting the ID's that will be updated for the history_table and then you can update them to the correct values.

Comment: thanks @jyncka the ordering is a good idea, playing with this as I have to also transform the selected rows column from value 0 to 1 on insert. I don't like that the transactions are non-atomic, but maybe that's ok.

Answer (score -1):

(I can't comment yet) Is there a specific reason to do it one query?
If not then you might use temporary table to store ids and fetch them for your update and insert using subquery.